# Apache Ignite vs Informix Warehouse Accelerator vs Infinispan?

Tags: informix, ignite, infinispan, in-memory-database, in-memory-data-grid

What's difference between Apache Ignite and IWA (Informix Warehouse Accelerator) and Infinispan ?
I have an application that accept large volume of data and process many transaction in per second. Not only 
response time is very important for us, but also Data integrity is very important for us, Which in-memory databases best solutions for me ?  , I'm confused 
to select them. also i use JEE and application server is jboss.
We are looking for best in-memory database solution to processing data in real time?
**Update:**
I use relational database , i am looking for in-memory database to select , insert , update from that for decrease response time, Also Data integrity is very important and very important persist data on disk

Answer (score 1):

`Apache Ignite` and `Infinispan` are both *data grids / memory-centric databases* with similar feature lists, with the biggest difference that `Apache Ignite` has `SQL` support for querying data.

Informix Warehouse Accelerator seems to be a narrow use case product, so it's hard to say if it's useful for your use case or not.

Otherwise, there's too few information in your question about the specifics of your project to say if either of those are a good fit, or even none of them.

Comment: @alirezaalallah I still don't understand. Do you want to replace your existing relational BD or just augment with caching?

Comment: Based on in-memory database features that we select, if  it support all our requirements( i explain in my post high select,update,delete 
With high data integrity)  then we switch to it, we are researching